# How to set "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" each time I'm connecting to sqlite db via Datagrip

Tags: sqlite, datagrip

In my pet project I'm working with small sqlite db and I've just came to realization that, in order to `ON DELETE CASCADE` actually do the thing, I need to set `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` each time I'm connecting to db.

However I'm using Datagrip and since it's quite new product to me I don't what's the best way to set this option every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, go the SQLite driver options, *Advanced* tab and set `true` to `foreign_keys` parameter.

[image]

Comment: What tool is that? I have the sqlite Python module.

Comment: It is DataGrip (or PyCharm Pro)

Answer (score 0):

As long as DataGrip does not have a built-in option for that, you have to write the command(s) in a startup script, and remember to configure it in the options of each new data source.